# Can I tell Carthage how to build my project that doesn't use xcode?

Tags: carthage, kotlin-native

I'm trying to provide an objective c framework to my iOS team who uses Carthage as their dependency manager. My project that I can compile to an Objective C framework doesn't use xcode to compile as I'm using [Kotlin/native](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native) - so carthage can't do it automatically.

I have a simple command I can run to build the objective c framework on any computer, but I need a way to instruct Carthage what that command is. I don't see anything in the documentation around this, just that Carthage can build `most` projects automatically.

**How can I tell carthage how to build my non-xcode project?**

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [at this conversation](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2783). I'm not sure that these instructions are up-to-date, but it might help, as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm aware that I can distribute a framework via a zip, but I'm specifically looking for a path to build kotlin/native locally on the host machine.